# getting typeERROR of tuple,even though the object is of type numpy.nparray()

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get the shape of a numpy array,but i'm getting typreERROR which says "'tuple' object is not callable".
Here's the code:-

```
labels=np.ones(length,dtype=int)
print(type(labels))
labels[:43]=0
labels[43:263]=1
labels[263:]=2
print(labels.shape())#produces error
```

if anyone could help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.shape` is an attribute of the array with a tuple, not a function that you need to call. So just change your code to: `print(labels.shape)`